# ReferenceError: "require" is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, pug

I am a beginner to node js and angular js.

I have a string which is html text and i want to convert it to jade.

I can do this with node js module 'html2jade' but when I am writing my code in js file (in controller), it is giving me a 'require' is not defined error.

This is the code:

```
app.controller('comicController', function($scope, resources) {

  $scope.searchComic = function() {
    resources.routes.charactersAPI.fetch({title: $scope.title}, function done(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $scope.comic = response;    
      //$scope.comic.description
      require('html2jade').convertHtml($scope.comic.description, {}, function (err, jade) {
            $scope.desc = jade;
          });
    });
  };

});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using requireJS? require() is a defeault command in node, but you need some library to make it available to you on the client-side. Which library are you using, and how?

Comment: You should use a module on your build process, like browserify

Comment: Do you already have installed the module?

Comment: i have installed the html2jade module

Answer (score 0):

You require a module on your build process.

Browsers don't have the require method defined, but Node.js does. With Browserify you can write code that uses require in the same way that you would use it in Node.

Install browserify

```
npm install -g browserify
```

Write a module

```
// hello.js
module.exports = function(name) {
    return 'Hello ' + name + '!';
}
```

Use the module

```
// app.js
var greetings = require('./hello');
alert(greetings('Christophe'));
```

Create the bundle

```
browserify app.js -o bundle.js
```

Refer your bundle

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Browserify is a tool that lets you bundle node.js modules and consume them in the browser. In other words, it allows you to write browser-based applications using node.js-style requires.

You can check [here](http://browserify.org/) for reference.

Comment: do u mean hello.js in place of bundle.js ? i.e. browserify app.js -o hello.js

Comment: And i have my response object inside controller so that data i want to use in my jade file

Comment: where do i write this?  -- browserify app.js -o bundle.js